# Defining default layout properties

Tags: wpf, templates, user-interface

I want to set consistent margins throughout all controls within an entire view.  I currently use XAML:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="ConsistentMargins">0,10,0,0</Thickness>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- ... -->
<!-- ... -->
<!-- ... -->

<MyControl1 Margin="{StaticResource ConsistentMargins}">
<MyControl2 Margin="{StaticResource ConsistentMargins}">
<MyControl3 Margin="{StaticResource ConsistentMargins}">
```

Is there a way to set a default layout style for controls to avoid the above repeated code shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own style with `TargetType` and this style will be assigned to all object of type which you specified in `TargetType`. But in this case your created style will be applied only for speciefied type of object, but not for derived type.

E.g. you can create style for all buttons like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0" />
</Style>
```

I think that this makes sense that style is not applied from base class, because I want say "My all buttons looks like...", but I want not say "Everything looks like...".

Comment: I think there are many cases which you do want to say, "everything looks like,"  the margins of any control as one good layout example.  Do you know of a way to get this working with the base type, so I could set TargetType to `x:Type Control` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may create a base default style, perhaps for FrameworkElement, and let the default styles for other element types extend the base style:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}"/>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}"/>
    <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}"/>
    ...
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: This adds the same amount of repeated code for many controls.

Comment: No, it doesn't. We are talking about *default styles* here. You define it once for every *type* of control, not for every *instance*, as in your example. For example you define the default style for TextBlocks once, afterwards the style gets applied to every TextBlock. That is actually a big difference, unless you have a strange UI that uses every control type exactly once.